# vim moving with hjkl in long lines (screen lines)

Tags: vim

[image]

The highlighted text is the array in which I want to move. I have to press g before pressing j to move a line down. Is there some mapping for my .vimrc that I can just use hjkl to move in screen lines without pressing g every time.

Thanks for your help
Matthias

Comment: I use VIM 7.2 and I don't need to hit g every time :-/

Comment: Mikhail, I have 7.2 and I need to. Probably it's a matter of configuration. To find if, for instance, j is already mapped to a sequence of commands, you can type ":map j".

Comment: I have VIM 7.2.33 and I have to press them.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I use the following snippet that helps with all forms of navigating, including things like $ to end of line and such.

```
" mapping to make movements operate on 1 screen line in wrap mode
function! ScreenMovement(movement)
   if &wrap
      return "g" . a:movement
   else
      return a:movement
   endif
endfunction
onoremap <silent> <expr> j ScreenMovement("j")
onoremap <silent> <expr> k ScreenMovement("k")
onoremap <silent> <expr> 0 ScreenMovement("0")
onoremap <silent> <expr> ^ ScreenMovement("^")
onoremap <silent> <expr> $ ScreenMovement("$")
nnoremap <silent> <expr> j ScreenMovement("j")
nnoremap <silent> <expr> k ScreenMovement("k")
nnoremap <silent> <expr> 0 ScreenMovement("0")
nnoremap <silent> <expr> ^ ScreenMovement("^")
nnoremap <silent> <expr> $ ScreenMovement("$")
```

Comment: Works like sugar :), thanks for this help. You have a very interesting and clean .vimrc on github.

Comment: Why do you need the options `<silent>` and `<expr>`? seems to work without them... Also, you could just use `"gj"` etc, instead of defining a function that does just that, especially since `gj` does exactly the same thing as `j` when the line isn't wrapped...

Answer (score 22):

You can remap the `j` and `k` keys (not sure if you really need `h` and `l`..)

```
:map j gj
:map k gk
```

Once you tried and liked them, add them to your `.vimrc` without the leading `:`

Comment: This works, but shouldn't you be using `:noremap`, so that the j doesn't recursively map? doesn't really matter in this example, but it's a good habit to get into...

Answer (score 7):

You can simply remap j and k (for example) to gj and gk:

```
" map j to gj and k to gk, so line navigation ignores line wrap
nmap j gj
nmap k gk
```

Comment: well, if you map these to your `.vimrc`, you may have problems later with macros or plugins. I know it is tedious to type `gj` and `gk`, maybe mapping it with leader will be a better choice.

Comment: @jelera what do you mean mapping with leader? So you have to type `<leader>j`? isn't that usually harder than `gj`?

Answer (score 1):

This is a great idea for when editing long text files, like latex documents. But it's not such a good idea when editing code, as it can screw up some macros (as jelera notes on Ned's answer). My compromise is to only enable it when in insert (and replace) modes, and not for anything else (I'm not aware of any macros that I use in insert mode that use navigation keys):

```
" move on soft lines in insert mode
inoremap <Down> <C-o>g<Down>
inoremap <Up> <C-o>g<Up>
```

(adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8347066/210945))