# Navigate between soft lines in Vim

Tags: vim, word-wrap

I have the following one-line text input that's broken into several soft line wraps.
[image: Vim screenshot with multiple soft line wraps]

When I press <kbd>j</kbd>, I'd go straight to the next hard line, line 2. How do I navigate among soft line wraps?

Comment: Why on .... did you not find the existing answers? This has been _frequently_ asked and answered

Comment: possible duplicate of [vim moving with hjkl in long lines (screen lines)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4946421/vim-moving-with-hjkl-in-long-lines-screen-lines)

Comment: @sehe: possibly because (1) the other questions are poorly worded (the questions themselves, not the detailed explanations that you only see if you open the page), or (2) the SE search engine sucks.  The question you give as an example is a perfect example of a not-so-clearly-worded question.

Comment: @iconoclast huh. The title doesn't get much clearer than that IMO

Comment: I immediately understood "soft lines", but "long lines" seemed to imply lines that are not wrapped.  Perhaps "long lines" is part of a vernacular used by hardcore vim devotees (many of whom probably already know the answer to questions like this) but it was not at all clear to me.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Use `gj` to go down and `gk` to go up by visual lines instead of hard lines.

Answer (score 14):

put that to your .vimrc:

```
map <silent> <Up> gk
imap <silent> <Up> <C-o>gk
map <silent> <Down> gj
imap <silent> <Down> <C-o>gj
map <silent> <home> g<home>
imap <silent> <home> <C-o>g<home>
map <silent> <End> g<End>
imap <silent> <End> <C-o>g<End>
```

Comment: I'd add that this worked for me with `noremap` instead of `map`. The `map` didn't worked.