# In vim, how to scroll, continuously, by screen lines when wrapping is enabled?

Tags: vim

I can get the bottom of the window to display partial lines by setting display=lastline

Is there a similar option that would allow partial lines to be displayed at the top of a window?

Without this functionality, my vim still scrolls (down) by more than 1 screen line when the topmost file line being displayed is wrapped into multiple screen lines.

For example, in the following scenario, when I press C-E, my vim will scroll down by 3 screen lines. Is there a way to make it scroll by only 1 screen line such that only the first two words in line 1 are hidden, but the following 3 words are still displayed? This will be very useful for editing long paragraphs of text.

Note: I'm referring to the scrolling of the entire screen, not the movement of cursor.

```
------------------
1 abcdefg abcefg
  abcasdfsa sdfsf
  sdfc
2 adfadf
3 adfadf
4 adfadf
------------------
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [vim moving with hjkl in long lines (screen lines)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4946421/vim-moving-with-hjkl-in-long-lines-screen-lines) (or see http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=vim+move+screen+lines)

Comment: @sehe Thanks for the help. But my problem is really different here. That one is concerning the movement of cursor. My question is concerning scrolling of the screen.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to do exactly what you want.

Here's the description I get when I type `:help CTRL-E`

```
                                                             CTRL-E
CTRL-E                      Scroll windows [count] lines downwards in the buffer.
                            Mnemonic: Extra lines.
```

Note that while it says it is scrolling the *window*, it also mentions that it is scrolling **lines in the buffer**.  You really are scrolling only one (wrapped) line at a time.

I don't think there's another way around this.

> I can get the bottom of the window to display partial lines by setting display=lastline

I think `display=lastline` is a false solution - you still scroll the same amount, you just have more visible.

**The real way to solve this is to *disable wrapping*:**

```
:set nowrap
```

**Edit**

Some related threads that show that a "scrolling via screen lines" feature is under consideration, but will take a while to be implemented:

- http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/Feature-request-Display-partial-paragraph-at-the-top-of-the-window-td1166809.html (4 years ago)
- http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/Scrolling-screen-lines-I-knew-it-s-impossible-td3358342.html (the beginning of this year.  Same dev mentioned wanting to implement it: "Ben Schmidt")

Comment: This kinda presents a problem if you have a line that is soo long that when wrapped doesn't fit into your window :/ (a border case, but still ...

Comment: @ldigas: I've run into that plenty of times, so I don't know how much of a border case that really is.  I think the `display=lastline` partially solves the display issue, but certainly not the usability issue.

Comment: @MerlynMorgan-Graham Thanks for the info! Maybe I should just stick to some other editor for long-paragraph editing.

Answer (score 2):

Now there's a built-in option for this:

```
'smoothscroll' 'sms'    boolean  (default off)
                        local to window
        Scrolling works with screen lines.  When 'wrap' is set and the first
        line in the window wraps part of it may not be visible, as if it is
        above the window. "<<<" is displayed at the start of the first line,
        highlighted with hl-NonText.
        NOTE: only partly implemented, currently works with CTRL-E, CTRL-Y  
        and scrolling with the mouse.
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone reading this thread:

[This thread](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/11315/visual-scrolling-visual-c-e-and-c-y-across-wrapped-lines/11383#11383) on the Vi stackexchange offers a slightly hacky (but useable) solution to visual scrolling across wrapped lines.