# Vim to always only jump one row at a time

Tags: vim, latex

I'm using Windows 7. I'm using Vim with line wrap. I have the following lines in my `_gvimrc`.

```
set wrap
set linebreak
set textwidth=0
set wrapmargin=0
set display+=lastline
```

This wraps text nicely. the last line, `set display+=lastline`, is to make sure that Vim always displays as much as possible of the last line. As you know, with line wrapping, very long lines get wrapped into what appears to be several rows, and without `set display+=lastline`, none of the long line at the bottom of page will display unless it is all visible. This is useful if you're writing articles in LaTeX for example. Now here is the problem. Sometimes I like to scroll down (or up) the screen by just pressing `j` at the bottom of page. With line wrapping and long lines (wrapped into several rows), pressing `j` at the bottom of page will make Vim jump several rows to make sure that the whole line, spanning several rows, is displayed. This behaviour makes it confusing for reading in Vim. How do I stop this behaviour? How do I make sure that Vim only jumps down by one row, even if that row is part of an incomplete line?

Please ask me to elaborate if that wasn't clear.

EDIT:

Just to be clear, I know how to make the cursor jump down by one row. I have the following lines in my `_gvimrc`.

```
nnoremap j gj
nnoremap k gk
nnoremap gj j
nnoremap gk k
```

What I would like to know is, when I jump down at the bottom of the displayed area, even with the above code in the `_gvimrc`, it still insists on displaying the whole long line. The cursor is where I expect it to be and it's good, but the screen still jumps several rows to display the whole long line. I would like to make the screen scroll only one row. Any suggestions?

Comment: I think the answer is you can't. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8369021/in-vim-how-to-scroll-continuously-by-screen-lines-when-wrapping-is-enabled

Comment: I feared that might be the answer. I continue my quest to find the perfect text editor.