# Formatting linebreaks from vim when working with other text editors

Tags: vim

I am writing screenplays in vim and using fountain for formatting. I have textwrap set to 80, so vim inserts a linebreak there for formatting. That is all well and good for my workflow in vim, but when I open the file in other text editor, the linebreaks remain. How do I avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to  avoid is to not  insert them. You can remove  your auto text
wrap by setting `'textwidth'` option to 0.

```
:set tw=0
```

Then, use the `'wrap'` option (which  defaults to on) to break you lines
on the  screen limit  (not inserting  a break,  just visually).  It will
break in  the middle of words  unless you set the  `'linebreak'` option.
Then it will break in the characters set by the `'breakat'` option.

This will mess  around a bit with  your `j` and `k`  movements in normal
mode, because they move by line. But you can use `gj` and `gk` to follow
"visual" line. Or remap them to do that automatically.

Be sure to check  the help for all those options  for a full description
and even more options!

Comment: Thank you so much! Is there a downside to remaping them to do it automatically? If not: how to remap them?

Comment: No downside, and can be done with a `:nnoremap j gj` and `:nnoremap k gk`. However, you can go more complex, with remapping operator pending mode for example, and algo can do something special for the [count to work](https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/2k4cbr/problem_with_gj_and_gk/). This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4952200/557306) has a nice "global" solution and the wiki also has an [article](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Move_cursor_by_display_lines_when_wrapping) on this subject. All depends on how far you want to go and which features to use! As usual with Vim, lots of options… :-D

Comment: Thanks so much man, helped out perfectly! Just one more thing: is there a way to add a 'margin' to the right side of the vim window? Because now the characters go all the way to the margin, and I'd like there to be more breathing space between them and the edge?

Comment: @oFca I don't think there is a specific option to this, but if you're running in a terminal you can use the `'columns'` option (check the help please). In GUI, but also for terminal, I think a nice solution would be to split your window vertically (`:vsplit` or _control+w_ and then _v_) and use it to wrap your text! I hope this explanation of the window split is clear enough

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good idea to have different format configuration for different editors.

The linebreaks remain because vim is inserting then.

If you want vim to wrap the text without insert breaks,  you must disable textwidth:

```
: set formatoptions-=t
: set wrap
```

And change your buffer size to 80 columns (change your terminal or split it vertically)

```
: vertical resize 80
```