# VIM: How do I move the cursor to the left of the screen?

Tags: vim

I know that `0` moves to the beginning of the line and `$` to the end of the line, but I am working with long lines with `nowrap` set. I want to jump to the left side of the screen.

How would I do that?

While we are at it, how do I jump to the right of the screen?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- `g0` to move to beginning
- `g$` to move to end
- `gm` to move to middle
- `g^` to move to first non-blank character

**Further Reading**

- start from `:h g_` for in-built help
- [vim moving with hjkl in long lines (screen lines)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4946421/vim-moving-with-hjkl-in-long-lines-screen-lines)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for.